# Remove all vowels in a string with Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am doing a homework assignment for my Computer Science course. The task is to get a users input, remove all of the vowels, and then print the new statement.

I know I could easily do it with this code:

```
string.replaceAll("[aeiou](?!\\b)", "")
```

But my instructor wants me to use nested if and else if statements to achieve the result. Right now I am using something like this:

```
if(Character.isLetter('a')){
    'do something'
}else if(Character.isLetter('e')){
    'do something else'
```

But I am not sure what to do inside the `if` and `else if` statements. Should I delete the letter? Or is there a better way to do this?

Seeing as this is my homework I don't want full answers just tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Character.isLetter('a')
```

[Character.isLetter(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) tells you if the value you give it is a letter, which isn't helpful in this case (you already know that "a" is a letter).

You probably want to use the equality operator, `==`, to see if your character is an "a", like:

```
char c = ...
if(c == 'a') {
    ...
} else if (c == 'e') {
    ...
}
```

You can get all of the characters in a String in multiple ways:

- As an array with [String.toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)
- Getting each character from the String using [String.charAt(index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

Answer (score 7):

I think what he might want is for you to read the string, create a new empty string (call it `s`), loop over your input and add all the characters that are not vowels to `s` (this requires an `if` statement). Then, you would simply print the contents of `s`.

---

**Edit:** You might want to consider using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for this because repetitive string concatenation can hinder performance, but the idea is the same. But to be honest, I doubt it would make a noticeable difference for this type of thing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can iterate through the character check if that is vowel or not as below:

```
  define a new string 
  for(each character in input string)
    //("aeiou".indexOf(character) <0) id one way to check if character is consonant
    if "aeiou" doesn't contain the character  
      append the character in the new string
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in O(n) time

- Iterate over the character array of your String
- If you hit a vowel skip the index and copy over the next non vowel character to the vowel position.
- You will need two counters, one which iterates over the full string, the other which keeps track of the last vowel position.
- After you reach the end of the array, look at the vowel tracker counter - is it sitting on a vowel, if not then the new String can be build from index 0 to 'vowelCounter-1'.

If you do this is in Java you will need extra space to build the new String etc. If you do it in C you can simply terminate the String with a null character and complete the program without any extra space.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your instructor wanted you to call `Character.isLetter('a')` because it's always `true`.

The simplest way of building the result without regexp is using a `StringBuilder` and a `switch` statement, like this:

```
String s = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    switch(c) {
        case 'a': // Fall through
        case 'u': // Fall through
        case 'o': // Fall through
        case 'i': // Fall through
        case 'e': break; // Do nothing
        default: // Do something
    }
}
s = res.toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

You can also replace this with an equivalent `if`, like this:

```
if (c!='a' && c!='u' && c!='o' && c!='i' && c!='e') {
    // Do something
}
```